# HList type parameter with required types in it

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I've got a project that relies heavily on the exact blueprint of its algorithm as it changes quite often. It deals with a list of things and those things have associated "facts" with them. I want to use HList to track those facts. Here's a working setup that I have (scala 2.11, shapeless 2.3.0):

```
import shapeless.{HList, HNil}

trait Fact

case class Fact1(v: Double = 0.5) extends Fact

case class Fact2(v: Double = 0.6) extends Fact

case class Fact3(v: Double) extends Fact

trait Thing

case class A(x: String = "whoah") extends Thing

def fact1(t: Thing) = Fact1()
def fact2(t: Thing) = Fact2()

case class Container[T <: HList](things: List[(Thing, T)]) {
  def addInfo[FactType <: Fact](f: Thing => FactType): Container[shapeless.::[FactType, T]] =
    copy(things = things.map(t => (t._1, f(t._1) :: t._2)))

  def compute[Info, FactType](f: (Thing, Info) => FactType)(t: T => Info): Container[shapeless.::[FactType, T]] = {
    copy(things = things.map { case (thing, facts) =>
      val info = t(facts)
      (thing, f(thing, info) :: facts)
    })
  }

  def compute1[Info, FactType](f: (Thing, T) => FactType): Container[shapeless.::[FactType, T]] = {
    copy(things = things.map { case (thing, facts) =>
      (thing, f(thing, facts) :: facts)
    })
  }
}

def computer(t: Thing, info: (Fact1, Fact2)) = Fact3(info._1.v + info._2.v)
// This obviously doesn't work

/*def computerNotWorking[Facts <: HList](t: Thing, facts: Facts)
                                      (implicit hs1: Selector[Facts, Fact1],
                                      hs2: Selector[Facts, Fact2) = {
  Fact3(facts.select[Fact1].v + facts.select[Fact2].v)
}*/

val lt = List(A("1") -> HNil, A("2") -> HNil)
val clt = Container(lt)

clt.addInfo(fact1)
  .addInfo(fact2)
  .compute(computer _) {
    facts => (facts.select[Fact1], facts.select[Fact2])
  }
//.compute1(computerNotWorking _) // see above why it doesn't work
```

So that's the problem. The justification for that is that I have lots of small functions and objects that do different parts of computation and due to nature of this algorithm (we experiment a lot with it), I would like remove and rearrange those things with minimum amount of code re-writing. And I want to keep those parts of the code only working with the specific facts they need to know about without knowing about anything else - to make testing easier and give each bit one single purpose.

The question, again: Is it possible to define a type called `HListWith[T1, T2, ...]` (upto random number of type arguments) that defines an HList with those `T*` types in it in any order?

Comment: can't you just have a number of `computer` methods that require implicit `Selector[Fact1, L]`, `Selector[Fact2, L]` etc in scope?

Comment: Tried your suggestion, didn't work as it says that requested implicit was not found. I'm not quite comfortable with shapeless (and its use of implicits) yet, may be I'm doing something wrong? Updated code in post

Comment: just change the last line with `.compute1((thing, facts) => computerNotWorking(thing, facts))`

Comment: In general with Shapeless you don't capture information about hlists using subtypes of `HList`, but by requiring type class instances that witness that the `HList` has the desired properties or operations. In this case specifically I think `ops.hlist.SelectAll` is what you want, but unfortunately it's brand new, so you might need to copy-paste for now.